# I am not able to stream video in rtmp

Tags: streaming, rtmp

I am getting error while streaming video

```
<html>

<body>

    <div id='container'>The player will be placed here</div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"> </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
              var flashvars = {
                file:'user2.flv',
                streamer:'rtmp://localhost/myapp/',
                type : 'video'
              };

              swfobject.embedSWF('player.swf','container','480','270','9.0.115','false', flashvars,

                   {allowfullscreen:'true',allowscriptaccess:'always'},
                   {id:'jwplayer',name:'jwplayer'}
              );
            </script>
</body>
```

[image]

CAn anyone help me fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you have a simple "it is not there" answer.  Questions to ask:

- Are you sure rtmp://localhost/myapp/user2.flv is a valid path?
- Are you running an RTMP server on your local machine?
- Does it have an app called myapp?
- Does the user2.flv actually exist?